# Do I need to enable App Engine Admin API for deployment?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

On GCP, I run Cloud Build from one project and deploy code to App Engine in another project. It looks like the project where build runs from needs to have App Engine Admin API enabled. Is it a real request or I missed the real configurations?

Comment: Can you share the step where you deploy in the other project?

Comment: I modified the example from [gcp](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine). The only difference is I have extra : `--project`. I don't think it is the step.

Answer (score 0):

[App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/overview) is required as it is used for any App Engine-related management operations

Also, based on the link above:

> The Admin API provides you with:
>
> - An integration point for your development and build tools.
> - Tighter control around deploying new versions, including the ability to automate traffic
> - migration between two versions or traffic splitting across one or more versions.
> - The ability to programmatically manage applications across multiple Google Cloud projects.

So yes, if you plan on deploying code to App Engine using Cloud Build, you need GAE Admin API enabled.

Comment: It makes senses to have App Engine API enabled in the targeted projects - it is needed to manage services and instances. But why is it needed in the project where build is running? This is the part I have problems to understand.

Comment: The normal way of deploying GAE apps is running `gcloud` commands via CLI. However, there are also ways for you to deploy your application using other products (such as Cloud Build) and that is where the Admin API comes in as it's used whenever you deploy or [manage your GAE apps programmatically](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/creating-an-application).

Comment: My question is related to Cloud Build deployment only. I have a project running Cloud Build but this project will not run any services using computing APIs. I want to know if there is a reason for deploying App Engine, the project running Cloud Build must have App Engine Admin API enabled even there is no App Engine instances. I have difficulty to understand the reasoning.